# which is faster in spark, collect() or toLocalIterator()

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark application in which I need to get the data from executors to driver and I am using `collect()`. However, I also came across `toLocalIterator()`. As far as I have read about `toLocalIterator()` on Internet, it returns an iterator rather than sending whole RDD instantly, so it has better memory performance, but what about speed? How is the performance between `collect()` and `toLocalIterator()` when it comes to execution/computation time?

Comment: RDD.toLocalIterator method can be written in a more efficient way to do the job. It uses runJob to evaluate only a single partition on each step. So, in that case, LocalIterator() will be faster

Answer (score 12):

The answer to this question depends on what would you do after making `df.collect()` and `df.rdd.toLocalIterator()`. For example, if you are processing a considerably big file about 7M rows and for each of the records in there, after doing all the required transformations, you needed to iterate over each of the records in the DataFrame and make a service calls in batches of 100.
In the case of `df.collect()`, it will dumping the entire set of records to the driver, so the driver will need an enormous amount of memory. Where as in the case of `toLocalIterator()`, it will only return an iterator over a partition of the total records, hence the driver does not need to have enormous amount of memory. So if you are going to load such big files in parallel workflows inside the same cluster, `df.collect()` will cause you a lot of expense, where as `toLocalIterator`() will not and it will be faster and reliable as well.

On the other hand if you plan on doing some transformations after `df.collect()` or `df.rdd.toLocalIterator()`, then `df.collect()` will be faster.

Also if your file size is so small that Spark's default partitioning logic does not break it down into partitions at all then `df.collect()` will be more faster.

Answer (score 10):

To quote from [the documentation on `toLocalIterator()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@toLocalIterator:Iterator[T]):

> This results in multiple Spark jobs, and if the input RDD is the result of a wide transformation (e.g. join with different partitioners), to avoid recomputing the input RDD should be cached first.

It means that in the worst case scenario (no caching at all) it can be n-partitions times more expensive than `collect`. Even if data is `cached`, the overhead of starting multiple Spark jobs can be significant on large datasets. However lower memory footprint can partially compensate that, depending on a particular configuration.

Overall, both methods are inefficient and should be avoided on large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

As for the toLocalIterator, it is used to collect the data from the RDD scattered around your cluster into one only node, the one from which the program is running, and do something with all the data in the same node. It is similar to the collect method, but instead of returning a List it will return an Iterator.

So, after applying a function to an RDD using foreach you can call toLocalIterator to get an iterator to all the contents of the RDD and process it. However, bear in mind that if your RDD is very big, you may have memory issues. If you want to transform it to an RDD again after doing the operations you need, use the SparkContext to parallelize it.